# Adding a class to the parent div of a specific image

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, instagram

```
  (function(){
  var photoTemplate, resource;

  function init(){
    bindEventHandlers();
    photoTemplate = _.template($('#photo-template').html());
  }

  function toTemplate(photo){
    photo = {
      count: photo.likes.count,
      avatar: photo.user.profile_picture,
      photo: photo.images.low_resolution.url,
      url: photo.link
    };

    return photoTemplate(photo);
  }

  function toScreen(photos){
    var photos_html = '';

    $('.paginate a').attr('data-max-tag-id', photos.pagination.next_max_id)
                    .fadeIn();

    $.each(photos.data, function(index, photo){
      photos_html += toTemplate(photo);
    });

    $('div#photos-wrap').append(photos_html);
  }

  function generateResource(tag){
    var config = Instagram.Config, url;

    if(typeof tag === 'undefined'){
      throw new Error("Resource requires a tag. Try searching for cats.");
    } else {
      // Make sure tag is a string, trim any trailing/leading whitespace and take only the first 
      // word, if there are multiple.
      tag = String(tag).trim().split(" ")[0];
    }

    url = config.apiHost + "/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?callback=?&client_id=" + config.clientID;

    return function(max_id){
      var next_page;
      if(typeof max_id === 'string' && max_id.trim() !== '') {
        next_page = url + "&max_id=" + max_id;
      }
      return next_page || url;
    };
  }


function paginate(max_id){    
        $.getJSON(generateUrl(tag), toScreen);
      }

      function search(tag){
        resource = generateResource(tag);
        $('.paginate a').hide();
        $('#photos-wrap *').remove();
        fetchPhotos();
      }

      function fetchPhotos(max_id){
        $.getJSON(resource(max_id), toScreen);
      }

      function bindEventHandlers(){
        $('body').on('click', '.paginate a.btn', function(){
          var tagID = $(this).attr('data-max-tag-id');
          fetchPhotos(tagID);
          return false;
        });

        // Bind an event handler to the `submit` event on the form
        $('form').on('submit', function(e){

          // Stop the form from fulfilling its destinty.
          e.preventDefault();

          // Extract the value of the search input text field.
          var tag = $('input.search-tag').val().trim();

          // Invoke `search`, passing `tag` (unless tag is an empty string).
          if(tag) {
            search(tag);
          };

        });

      }

      function showPhoto(p){
        $(p).fadeIn();
      }

      // Public API
      Instagram.App = {
        search: search,
        showPhoto: showPhoto,
        init: init
      };
    }());

    $(function(){
      Instagram.App.init();

      // Start with a search on yogofactory; we all love frozen yogurt :).
      Instagram.App.search('yogofactory');  
    });
```

it then goes to the HTML file and builds the gallery around this

```
<script type="text/template" id="photo-template">
      <div class='photo'>
          <img class='main' src='<%= photo %>' width='250' height='250' style='display:none;' onload='Instagram.App.showPhoto(this);' />
        <img class='avatar' width='40' height='40' src='<%= avatar %>' />
        <span class='heart'><strong><%= count %></strong></span>
      </div>
</script>
```

I'm not to experienced when it comes to JS or jQuery. I'm looking for a way to add a class to the parent `<div class="photo">`, when the image inside is `src="http://image.com/onlythisone.jpg"` and only when its that image.

I have a gallery a large gallery pulling dynamically from the instagram database, I basically want to be able to hide certain photos that don't follow the hash tag rules I created for my promotion.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only way to gain experience is to try things on your own.

Comment: How about `$('img[src="http://image.com/onlythisone.jpg"]').parent().addClass('your_class')`?

Comment: Where's the `toScreen()` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function written in javascript that when called with the attributes set to the image's src value and a class name, will search all images and add the specified class to it's parent if it doesn't already exist. Just run the function after loading any images.

```
function addClassToSpecificImageParent(imageUrl, className) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), function (element) {
        if (element.src === imageUrl && !element.parentNode.classList.contains(className)) {
            element.parentNode.classList.add(className);
        }
    });
}

addClassToSpecificImageParent("http://image.com/onlythisone.jpg", "someClass");
```

;

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/D3QAa/)

Update: based on the code that you have now posted, you would add the call to the above function, as shown below

```
function toScreen(photos) {
    var photos_html = '';

    $('.paginate a').attr('data-max-tag-id', photos.pagination.next_max_id)
        .fadeIn();

    $.each(photos.data, function (index, photo) {
        photos_html += toTemplate(photo);
    });

    $('div#photos-wrap').append(photos_html);

    addClassToSpecificImageParent("http://image.com/onlythisone.jpg", "someClass");
}
```

Update: An alternative, now you have posted more detail, is to use the Underscore template

HTML - Underscore Template

```
<script type="text/template" id="photo-template">
      <div class='photo<%= extraclass %>'>
        <img class='main' src='<%= photo %>' width='250' height='250' style='display:none;' onload='Instagram.App.showPhoto(this);' />
        <img class='avatar' width='40' height='40' src='<%= avatar %>' />
        <span class='heart'><strong><%= count %></strong></span>
      </div>
</script>
```

Javascript

```
function toTemplate(photo) {
    photo = {
        count: photo.likes.count,
        avatar: photo.user.profile_picture,
        photo: photo.images.low_resolution.url,
        url: photo.link,
        extraclass: ""
    };

    if (photo.link === "http://image.com/onlythisone.jpg") {
        photo.extraclass = " someclass";
    }

    return photoTemplate(photo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I run this function after the gallery gets built?

Comment: Just call the function, as demonstrated above, at the point in your code after the "gallery gets built". Looking at your update, perhaps as part of "toScreen" function as the very last action.

Comment: Otherwise the only other way would be to use Mutation Events/Observer to watch the DOM for changes and execute the function when it sees an Image added or modified.

Comment: Adding it to the last part of the toScreen Section has seemed to work! Thank you sooooo much for you time and help!

Comment: No problem, of course you could do exactly the same thing with @adeneo jquery solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
    $('img[src="http://image.com/onlythisone.jpg"]').parent().addClass('myClass')
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
function toScreen(photos) {
    var photos_html = '';

    $('.paginate a').attr('data-max-tag-id', photos.pagination.next_max_id)
        .fadeIn();

    $.each(photos.data, function (index, photo) {
        photos_html += toTemplate(photo);
    });

    photos_html.find('img[src="http://image.com/onlythisone.jpg"]').remove();

    $('div#photos-wrap').append(photos_html);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would solve anything close to what OP is describing.

Comment: @squint - It adds a class to the parent of the image when the source matches that exact string, which sounds like exactly what the OP is asking for ?

Comment: If it was a static URL, and only needed to occur on page load, then sure. But the question describes more complexity than just that.

Comment: @squint - Then we're not reading the same question? It states that the OP is looking for a way to add a class to the parent element of any image that has a src attribute matching a certain string ?

Comment: *"I have a gallery a large gallery pulling dynamically from the instagram database, I basically want to be able to hide certain photos that don't follow the hash tag rules I created for my promotion."*

Comment: @squint - who cares about any of that, there's no code posted and no further information on how that is done, the hash tag rules are'nt posted etc. The only real question is how to add a class to a parent if the source of the image matched a string ?

Comment: @RaufTür - if the script that creates the gallery is loading the images dynamically, you probably have to post the code in a callback function to some sort of ajax request etc. when the images are actually loaded.

Comment: @squint You're very correct. Thats the EXACT functionality i'm looking for, but it doesn't work on the page since its not a static url.

Comment: @adeneo: Exactly... Whatever needs to be done is certainly more than this, but there's not enough information or effort shown in the question. Should be closed if anything.

Comment: I could most defiantly give more information. This is my first post here, sorry if i wasn't clear on the help.

Comment: @RaufTür: You clearly have some working code if you have a gallery set up. You should show what you have so far and describe exactly where you're stuck. You can edit your question to provide more info.

Comment: +1 this jquery solution adds some class to the parent of an image with a specific src value

Comment: @squint - thanks for the advice, i posted the JS that pulls the images, and then i also updated section where the gallery gets built. All the solutions work if its static, but since i have it dynamically pulling the images its not adding the class.

Comment: @RaufTür - I'm still missing the toScreen() function, that's the important one ?

Comment: @adeneo - Sorry! Must of got cut off, i posted it now.! :(